# What is the best hosting option for Flash web-widget?

Tags: hosting, flash

Our Flash web-widget has got highly popular.
It is downloaded around 100,000 times per day.
And that is the problem.
Our server bandwidth is too narrow to deliver the widget to the clients fast.
The widget is loaded very slow. 
Probably 20 times slower than before (at peak times).

Probably I have choosen not the right hoster for my task - delivering 1 MB Flash widget to 100,000 users per day.
What is the best hosting solution in my case?

I'm not good at server administration so forgive me if I sound naive.

The details are the following.

```
Our hoster options:
-Dedicated server, Ubuntu
-10 Mbit Connection
-monthly bandwidth limit: 2000 GB
```

Widget size is 1 MB.
The widget consists of the main SWF and a number of loaded SWF and data files.

This is a part of Apache Status report taken right now

```
----
Server uptime: 1 hour 2 minutes 38 seconds
Total accesses: 74865 - Total Traffic: 5.8 GB
CPU Usage: u28 s7.78 cu0 cs0 - .952% CPU load
19.9 requests/sec - 1.6 MB/second - 81.1 kB/request
200 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers

WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWCWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWCWWWWWWWCWWWW
WWWWWCWWWWWWWWWWWWWWCWWWWWWWWWWWWCWWWWWWWWCWWCWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWCWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWCWCWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWCW
WWWWWWWW........................................................
----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on TomTom's answer:

I don't know how proficient You are at the hole business, I'll start with the basics.

At 1.6 MB/second Your 10 Mbit link, as You surely know, is maxed out. You need a bigger pipe.

Your Widget is 1 MB big, so You can only serve the data amount of say 1.4 times the widget per second for every 10 Mbit You have.

Most providers with unmetered 100 MBit offers will switch down to 10 Mbit after usage of about 5 GB. So thats no option for You.

Dedicated unmetered 100 Mbit is expensive but might even not solve the problem.

What You need is so called burstable bandwidth and that comes with the premium TonTom pointed out.

If Money is a problem but You are not afraid that any IP could be stolen, You might want to think about calling the Widget from somwhere else where bandwidth is cheap if the region is connected to Your market good enough. In europe this can be had from china and russia, as it's the same continent. With simple file serving, latency should not be that much a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that has a lot more bandwidth. Ignore limit - at this region you have to pay by mbit or gbyte anyway, any flat thing is just not going to work out.

A hoster should be able to deliver you peak rates of 1gbit from his computer without problems.